# How to run mule runtime as different user?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, mule, anypoint-studio

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.2 and Mule runtime 3.8.3.

I want to log into an SQL Server database using Windows Auth and an article that says I should

> "connect to the MS SQL Server database using the credentials of the
>   user running the Mule runtime process by providing the
>   integratedSecurity=true parameter to the JDBC URL. Something like this:  **jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver;integratedSecurity=true;**"

How do I find the username against the mule runtime or change the username to something different?

Thanks

Comment: If it is Windows Authentication you will be hitting SQL Server using the Windows account which runs this client. If you want to run using different context you might require to run this process using different windows user context

Answer (score 0):

If your Anypoint Studio is Windows application, you can launch it using [runas command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx) indicating account you want to pass to SQL Server (or `shift + right click` on the program icon using GUI -> Run as different user)

You can also change login context from your T-SQL code, see [EXECUTE AS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql)

Example:

```
execute as login = 'MyDomain\MyAccount';
select system_user;
```

You should have `IMPERSONATE` on that login for be able to do it in your code